# Epimorphisms in the simplex category $\Delta$

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff

Let $\Delta$ be the category of finite nonempty ordinals, known as the *simplex category.* Its objects are finite nonempty ordinals and its morphisms are order-preserving maps between those. I want to know if every epimorphism in $\Delta$ is surjective.

There are well-known proofs of the fact that monomorphisms (resp., epimorphisms) in $\mathsf{Set}$ are precisely injective (resp., surjective) functions. The proof of the monomorphism case carry out line-by-line as the one-element set $\{0\}$ is a finite ordinal and any function $f\colon\{0\}\to n$ is trivially order-preserving. The same cannot be said about epimorphisms. If $f\colon m\to n$ is an epimorphism in $\Delta$ which is not surjective (a start of a proof by contradiction) and $k \in n\setminus\mathrm{im}(f)$, then a function $g\colon n\to n\cup\{n\} = n + 1$ defined by $g(k') = k$ if $k' \neq k$ and $g(k) = n$ is not necessarily order-preserving (this is a step in the proof that every epimorphism in $\mathsf{Set}$ is surjective where instead of $n$ we take any $a$ such that $a \notin n$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All maps here will be (weakly) order-preserving.

Let $f:[m]\to[n]$ not be surjective. We claim there are distinct maps $g_1,g_2
:[n]\to[n]$ with $g_1\circ f\ne g_2\circ f$. Suppose $j$ is omitted from the
image of $f$. Let $g_1$ be the identity, and $g_2$ be the identity on all elements
other than $j$ and also $g_2(j)=j-1$ or $j+1$ (one of which is in $[n]$).

This works unless $n=1$, and then $m$ must be $0$, in which case we need some
*ad hoc* argument.

Comment: For $n = 1$, $m$ is not necessarily $0$, but it doesn't matter. Since $f\colon [m]\to [1]$ is not surjective, we either have $f(i) = 0$ for all $i$ or $f(i) = 1$ for all $i$. In the first case, consider $g_1,g_2\colon [1]\to [2]$ with $g_1(0) = 0 = g_2(0), g_1(1) = 1$ and $g_2(1) = 2$. In the second, let $g_1(0) = 0, g_2(0) = 1$ and $g_1(1) = 2 = g_1(1)$.